# What's git's heuristic for assigning content modifications to file paths?

Tags: git

Short version:

> short of poring over `git`'s source code, where can I find a full description of the heuristics that `git` uses to associate chunks of content with specific tracked pathnames?

---

Detailed version:

In the (Unix) shell demo interaction below, two files, `a` and `b`, are "`git-commit`'ted", then they are modified so as to (effectively) transfer most of `a`'s content to `b`, and finally the two files are once more commited.

**The key thing to look for is that the output of the second `git commit` ends with the line**

```
rename a => b (99%)
```

**even though no renaming of files (in the usual sense) ever took place (!?!).**

---

Before showing the demo, this brief description may make it easier to follow.

The contents of the files `a` and `b` are generated by combining the contents of the three auxiliary files, `../A`, `../B`, and `../C`.  Symbolically, the states of `a` and `b` could be represented as

```
../A + ../C -> a
../B        -> b
```

right before the first commit, and

```
../A        -> a
../B + ../C -> b
```

right before the second one.

OK, here's the demo.

---

First, we display the contents of auxiliary files `../A`, `../B`, and `../C`:

```
head ../A ../B ../C
# ==> ../A <==
# ...
# 
# ==> ../B <==
# ###
# 
# ==> ../C <==
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
```

(Lines beginning with `#` correspond to output to the terminal; the actual output lines do not have the leading `#`.)

Next, we create files `a` and `b`, display their contents, and commit them

```
cat ../A ../C > a
cat ../B      > b
head a b
# ==> a <==
# ...
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# 
# ==> b <==
# ###

git add a b
git commit --allow-empty-message -m ''
# [master (root-commit) 3576df7] 
#  2 files changed, 8 insertions(+)
#  create mode 100644 a
#  create mode 100644 b
```

Next, we modify files `a` and `b`, and display their new contents:

```
cat ../A      > a
cat ../B ../C > b
head a b
# ==> a <==
# ...
#
# ==> b <==
# ###
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
```

Finally, we commit the modified `a` and `b`; note the output of `git commit`:

```
git add a b
git commit --allow-empty-message -m ''
# [master 25b806f] 
#  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
#  rewrite a (99%)
#  rename a => b (99%)
```

---

I rationalize this behavior as follows.

As I understand it, `git` treats directory structure info (such as the pathnames of the files it's tracking) as *secondary* information—or metadata, if you will—, to be associated with the *primary* information it tracks, namely various chunks of content.

Since both the contents as well as the names (including pathnames) of files may change between commits, `git` must use heuristics to associate pathnames to chunks of content.  But heuristics, by their very nature, are not guaranteed to work 100% of the time.  A failure of such heuristics here takes the form of a history that does not faithfully represent what actually happened (e.g. it reports a file renaming even though no file was renamed, in the usual sense).

A further confirmation of this interpretation (namely, that some heuristics are at play) is that, AFAICT, if the size of the transferred chunk is not sufficiently large, the output of `git commit` will not include the `rewrite/rename` lines.  (I include a demonstration of this case at the end of this post, FWIW.)

> My question is this: short of poring over `git`'s source code, where can I find a full description of the heuristics that `git` uses to associate chunks of content with specific tracked pathnames?

---

This second demo is identical to the first one in every way, except that the auxiliary file `../C` is one line shorter than before.

```
head ../A ../B ../C
# ==> ../A <==
# ...
# 
# ==> ../B <==
# ###
# 
# ==> ../C <==
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================

cat ../A ../C > a
cat ../B      > b
head a b
# ==> a <==
# ...
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# 
# ==> b <==
# ###

git add .
git commit -a --allow-empty-message -m ''
# [master (root-commit) a06a689] 
#  2 files changed, 7 insertions(+)
#  create mode 100644 a
#  create mode 100644 b

cat ../A      > a
cat ../B ../C > b
head a b
# ==> a <==
# ...
# 
# ==> b <==
# ###
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================
# =================================================================

git add .
git commit -a --allow-empty-message -m ''
# [master 87415a1] 
#  2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Note that similarity of files has no effect whatsoever on commits. Commits are *snapshots* of the working directory, where the difference to the previous versions does not matter. The similiarity is solely generated by the porcelain commands on output.

Answer (score 10):

As you noticed, Git performs rename detection using a heuristic, rather than being told that a rename occurred.  The `git mv` command, in fact, simply stages an add on the new file path and a remove of the old file path.  Thus, rename detection is performed by comparing the contents of added files to the previously committed contents of deleted files.

First, candidates are collected.  Any new files are possible rename targets and any deleted files are possible rename sources.  In addition, rewriting changes are broken such that a file that is more than 50% different than its previous revision is both a possible rename source and a possible rename target.

Next, identical renames are detected.  If you rename a file without making any changes, then the file will hash identically.  These can be detected just performing comparisons of the hash in the index without reading the file contents, so removing these from the candidate list will reduce the number of comparisons you need to perform.

Finally, the similarity comparison is performed.  Each line in each candidate file is hashed and collected in a sorted list.  Long lines are split at 60 characters.  Whitespace only lines may be stripped on the assumption that they don't contribute greatly to the similarity matching.  The line hashes from each candidate source are compared to the line hashes from each candidate target.  If two lists are 60% similar, they are deemed a rename.

Comment: So it's always by source lines?  (Assuming a non-binary diff anyway.)  (This *is* a question; I don't know the answer! :-)  Not sure that it matters that much either, just curious.)

Comment: Yes, always by lines, at least in git.git.  github.com/libgit2/libgit2 allows for a pluggable similarity detection, though the default implementation uses the core git strategy.

Comment: The splitting of lines, by the way, should facilitate binary rename detection as well!

Comment: Assuming they split well, perhaps.  A straight rename is much easier to detect, as the SHA-1 for the blobs will match.  (I have not looked but I assume this is done first to reduce candidate counts for remaining rename detections.)

Comment: @torek Definitely so - thank you for reminding me of this very important detail.

Answer (score 2):

> ... short of poring over git's source code, where can I find a full description of the heuristics that git uses to associate chunks of content with specific tracked pathnames?

Depending on what you mean by "full" I don't think you can find such a thing.  (In particular, how are "percentages" calculated?  Is it by lines, or characters/bytes, or something else?  Does doing a word-oriented diff change things?)  But the magic is all inside `git diff`, where it is computed dynamically every time a diff is to be shown; and the heuristics have several control knobs that give strong clues:

> `--no-renames`
>
> Turn off rename detection, even when the configuration file gives
>              the default to do so.
>
> `-B[<n>][/<m>], --break-rewrites[=[<n>][/<m>]]`
>
> Break complete rewrite changes into pairs of delete and create.
>              This serves two purposes:
>
> - It affects the way a change that amounts to a total rewrite of a
>            file not as a series of deletion and insertion mixed together with
>            a very few lines that happen to match textually as the context, but
>            as a single deletion of everything old followed by a single
>            insertion of everything new, and the number m controls this aspect
>            of the -B option (defaults to 60%).  `-B/70%` specifies that less
>            than 30% of the original should remain in the result for Git to
>            consider it a total rewrite (i.e. otherwise the resulting patch
>            will be a series of deletion and insertion mixed together with
>            context lines).
> - When used with `-M`, a totally-rewritten file is also considered as
>            the source of a rename (usually `-M` only considers a file that
>            disappeared as the source of a rename), and the number n controls
>            this aspect of the -B option (defaults to 50%).  `-B20%` specifies
>            that a change with addition and deletion compared to 20% or more of
>            the file's size are eligible for being picked up as a possible
>            source of a rename to another file.

and so on; see the [documentation for git-diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Comment: By lines.  Though long lines get split at some length (60 chars? I forget, offhand)