# git status shows rename but it's incorrect

Tags: git, rename

I use Rails to develop. I have a controller named `cpc_admin_controller.rb` the full path is `app/controllers/cpc_admin_controller.rb`, and a helper named `admin_helper.rb` the full path is `app/helpers/admin_helper.rb`. Then I remove a method from `admin_helper.rb` to `cpc_admin_controller.rb`, and save, use git to commit.

But the git show the messages as follows

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    app/helpers/admin_helper.rb ->    app/controllers/cpc_admin_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/helpers/admin_helper.rb
```

I think it should show two modified like this, not the renamed

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   app/controllers/cpc_admin_controller.rb
#   modified:   app/helpers/admin_helper.rb
```

Someone can help me, tell me why?

Comment: At last, i commit,  the `app/controllers/cpc_admin_controller.rb` and `app/helpers/admin_helper.rb` still there, The file name has not renamed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As illustrated in [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/171932)

> Git doesn't care about individual files or renames, it tracks whole trees.
>   What it shows as a rename is just its best guess based on the contents of the two files.

Git status does [perform rename detection using a heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292993/6309).
But once you commit, you will see the two files are kept separate.

Comment: Thank you very much. When i read [perform rename detection using a heuristic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292993/6309), i reappear my issue.