# git incorrectly tags a file as rename

Tags: git

I have two files which are already added and committed in git.

> report
>   report_dates

Now, I have modified both the files and am trying to commit but git incorrectly tags report_dates file as renamed after I add them to the staging area.

```
> git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:  
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)  
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)  
      modified:   report
      modified:   report_dates

> git add report
> git add report_dates

> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
      renamed:    report_dates -> report
      modified:   report_dates
```

I tried verifying using **git commit --dry-run** and that too shows the file as renamed. Will committing overwrite the original file? There are two different files with 90% content similar.

Comment: This is how git works. Sometimes it won't detect actual renames if the file content changes too much. You should accept it and move on :)

Comment: Same in http://stackoverflow.com/q/26273245/6309: a git status *after* commit will work.

Comment: Thanks @VonC `git commit --dry-run` shows it as rename. Can I still go ahead and commit?  

@AlexMDC This is not a rename but git reports it as a rename.

Comment: Sure: if it doesn't work out, you still can reset to the previous commit.

Comment: shows correctly after the commit

Comment: Great. I just posted an answer detailing why the `git status` seems strange before commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained before in "[`git status` shows rename but it's incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26273245/6309)", you would need to actually commit before seeing the right status.

A `git status` *before* commit:

- remains based on the index, which looks like renames have been taken place.
  Sometimes a `git commit --dry-run -a` (note the `-a`) can help.
- detects:

  - `report_dates` [being moved](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files) (renamed in `report`)
  - `report_dates` being modified

It (the `git status`) won't know *for sure* until you actually commit: you might still deleted `report_dates` before said commit.

But the actual commit will register both files (no override), and a new `git status` won't show any rename (as [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325605/git-incorrectly-tags-a-file-as-rename/26327420#comment41318054_26325605) by the [OP shnazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134474/shnazz)).