# Git changing repo directory and files directory

Tags: git

I end up moving my git repo to another directory and also the change directory of all my files.

Now when I add file to index and commit it, it acts as if it is committing a new file and not committing the difference. Eventhough when I pull up the history in Git Extension, all the history is there, and the most recent commit is still appending to the master as if nothing ever happen.

Probably I don't know enough how git to works that it is how it's suppose to work? Suggestions? or anyone need me to clarify?

Comment: Did you use `git mv` to change the directory of all your files?

Comment: @isim, no i did not, moved it in windows explorer. Did I screwed up my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that [Git performs rename detection using a heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292993/6309)

That means, as I explained in "[`git status` shows rename but it's incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273402/6309)", that:

- a `git add` alone might consider the file added to the index a "new" file
- but a `git commit` should reconcile the state of that file, and display it as being moved.

So check (when you are ready to commit) the output of a `git commit`, to see if the "new" file status persists.

Comment: after I did "git status" than "git comment". I get a bunch of "Changes not staged for commit" showing a files "deleted" which are all files that was in the old directory. Under "Untracked files:" are my files after the files that are moved into the new directory.

Comment: You need to add everything before committing: `git add -A .` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/572549/6309), before git commit -m "move files"`. Then the `git status` should reflect the moves.