# How does git status work internally?

Tags: git

From the [git object model](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), files and folders are saved to locations in the .git folder by their sha1 hash.

How does git internally know if a file has been deleted, added, or edited (specifically, how does it compute the changes you see when you type `git status`)? Does the system determine this information purely from the sha1?

Comment: Basically, it scans the disk. if it sees a new file, then it reports as "untracked"; if there's a file in the repo that is not in the tree, then it reports it as "deleted". If the file is present both in the repo and on the disk, then it calculates the sha-1 of the file on disk and if it's different from the sha-1 in the repo, it reports as "modified". A lot of caching and other tricks are performed to keep this fast.

Comment: I have wrote you a detailed answer with screenshots to clarify the answer. Feel free to ask if something is not clear enough.

Comment: The index lists tracked pathnames and has the sha1 of the content tracked at each path along with metadata and notes about things like the source data for inflight merges.  git status scans the filesystem and compares current metadata against the index, anytime it detects a potential mismatch it rescans content if necessary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is bit too long and will take a while to write so here is the summary.

The short answer is that git uses the `SHA-1` to check track changes but the name of the file is stored somewhere else.

---

The content is stored in a `pack` <sup>(*1- read below)</sup> while the names are stored in a `idx`.
When you run `git status`, git check to see if already have this path in the idx file (metadata) and based upon the result it decide if it's a new file or not.

If it's not a new file, git comparing the SHA-1 to track changes.

---

### Why do I have to use git mv to move files and not a simple mv?

When you execute `git status` git search your working directory looking for a match between the **"registered"** paths in the idx file and your working directory.

When you move a file with `mv` your working directory does not have the "original" path stored by git, and since git can't find the "registered" path anymore, the file is marked as deleted.

**But** on the same time git see a new file, the **new** path you just the moved the file to, so the **new** file will be marked as a new file.

On the other hand, when using `git mv`, git updates the metadata to point to the new name and the content will be marked as **rename**. In this case git updates the registered path of the file in the idx file.
If you move and update it will be marked as rename + modified as well.

[image]
[image]

---

### How can I find out what is the SHA-1 of a file?

Use the `git ls-tree` internal command to find out what is the SHA-1 of your files.

[image]

---

***Note***

Git starts to track content when you just add it to the staging area.
Once the file is added git store the following information in the file

```
[blob][1 white space][content length][null][content]

If you have a file with the string `hello` it will look like this:
blob 5\0Hello
```

Now git calculate the SHA-1 of this file (using `sha1sumn`) compress it with z-lib and save the file with this SHA-1 as the name nuder the `.git/objects'.

When git packs the repository it will go into the pack file.

### How can I view the content of the file?

Since the file is compressed with z-lib we have several options to get the content:

- First option is to view the zipped stored in the file
- Second is to view the unzipped content (as explained above)
- See the content of the file only without any git metadata.

[image]

And to show that git actually use the content as described above here is the same command as git executes behind the scenes to calculate the SHA-1

[image]

---

### This is the illustration of a commit and how it handles file names.

(http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html)
[image]

Comment: You're conflating the git index (which tracks paths) and a pack file's index (which provides a mapping of object id to location in the pack file.)

Comment: I agree, its too long so i tried to summarize it without going into too much details. Feel free to edit and add your content. Appricated

Answer (score 19):

[CodeWizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922283/1256452) is wrong in a few important details, as [Edward Thomson noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson).

The super-short version is that `git status` runs `git diff`.

In fact, it runs it *twice*, or more precisely, it runs two different internal variations on `git diff`: one to compare `HEAD` to the index/staging-area, and one to compare the staging-area to the work-tree.  It runs each diff with a request to search for renames, i.e., sets the `-M` flag (see below).  Finally, it presents the results from these diffs to you in whichever format you requested.  In no case does it show the actual changes between files, though (so in effect it runs these diffs with `--name-status` as well).

#### Using the various diffs

You can run both of these internal diffs manually: one has a front-end command spelled [`git diff-index --cached`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-index.html), and one has a front-end command spelled [`git diff-files`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-files.html).  This front-end selection is captured in the slightly oddly placed section titled [**Raw output format**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-index.html#_raw_output_format) (I have had to modify this a bit to display better on StackOverflow):

> The raw output format from `git-diff-index`, `git-diff-tree`, `git-diff-files` and `git diff --raw` are very similar.
>
> These commands all compare two sets of things; what is compared differs:
>
> `git-diff-index tree-ish`
>        compares the *`tree-ish`* and the files on the filesystem.
>
> `git-diff-index --cached tree-ish`
>         compares the *`tree-ish`* and the index.
>
> `git-diff-tree [-r] tree-ish-1 tree-ish-2 [pattern ...]`
>         compares the trees named by the two arguments.
>
> `git-diff-files [pattern ...]`
>         compares the index and the files on the filesystem.

(You can invoke these with regular `git diff` as well: `git diff --cached` compares the current (`HEAD`) commit to the staging-area, and `git diff` with no additional arguments compares the staging-area to the work-tree.)

#### Mapping trees back to paths

CodeWizard's answer has the keys to this process.  Essentially, a *tree* object contains the path-name component (such as the `foo` or `bar` in `foo/bar`) and another object ID.  If the component represents a directory, the object ID locates another tree object; if it represents a file, the object ID locates a blob object.  In either case the ID is Git's internal name, which enables Git to find it in the repository.

(This is not true for the index/staging-area itself, whose format is not very well documented.  It is a flat list of all files, with full path names but using a name compression technique as well, so that `VeryLongDirectory/AnotherLongDirectory/bar` followed by `VeryLongDirectory/AnotherLongDirectory/baz` does not have to spell out `VeryLongDirectory/AnotherLongDirectory` each time.)

(Tree objects also store the mode that Git should assign to the file, upon extraction, except that in the tree object, each file mode is only ever `100644` or `100755`; the final `rwx` bits are set based on your umask, assuming a Unix-like host, with `x` being always-clear if the stored mode is `100644`, otherwise set-except-as-cleared-by-umask.)

#### Unstaged files and detecting renames

> How does git internally know if a file has been deleted, added, or edited (specifically, how does it compute the changes you see when you type git status)?

A file that is in the work-tree, but is neither in the `HEAD` commit *nor* in the index/staging-area is *unstaged* (this is in fact the definition of "unstaged").  Git finds such files by looking at all three (and using the index/staging-area for cache information to speed up the process).  All the unstaged file paths are generally fed to the "ignore" code, which makes git shut up about them if they are listed in `.gitignore` or any of the other ignore-some-paths files.

Having dispensed with unstaged paths, let's consider the remaining paths, which (by definition) appear in at least one of `HEAD` or the index/staging-area.

In general—there are more flags for controlling this in finer detail, although `git status` does not set any of them—Git first compares the path names available in the "A" side (`a/foo/bar`) to those in the "B" side (`b/foo/bar`).  If the same path appears in *both* sides, chances are that the file was simply modified in place, and Git starts with that assumption.  If a path appears in A but not in B, and some other path appears in B but not in A, the two paths are paired up and given to to the *rename detector* (if it is enabled).

All the internal diffs share a bunch of code, and also share the documentation.  Click on one of the above links and search for `-M` or `--find-renames`:

> `-M[n]
>   --find-renames[=n]`
>
> Detect renames. If *n* is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, `-M90%` means Git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than `90%` of the file hasn’t changed. Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes `0.5`, and is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`. The default similarity index is `50%`.

The rename-detector can be enabled by default by setting `diff.renameLimit` to `0` in your configuration.  Otherwise, it is currently disabled by default, but will be enabled by default in an upcoming Git release (I am not sure which one).

For further detail on the similarity matching, see [this answer from **Edward Thomson**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292993/1256452).

Once the rename detector decides that some A-to-B change is a rename, it pulls both names out of the "only in A" and "only in B" lists.

#### Added and deleted

After running the rename detector (if enabled), any files that are found only on the A side are "deleted", and any found only on the B side are "added".  For `git status`, this concludes the whole process (except for displaying the results).  For regular `git diff` we usually go on to produce actual diff output, when some file is modified or renamed-and-modified.

(Note that all of Git's diffs share all of this machinery, so they will all find the same set of renames, provided you turn on rename detection and set the same thresholds.  These are also used during `git merge`.)

#### Side note: renames are *detected*, not *recorded*

Many other version control systems (Mercurial, ClearCase, Perforce) require that you register a file-rename with them: `hg mv` and so on.  This is because they *record* the rename with each commit.  A system that does this necessarily gives each file some kind of identifier (this could be a true object ID as in ClearCase, or simply "its name in the current commit", which is then munged as needed as we move from commit to commit).  The advantage to this system is that the VCS can follow the file no matter how changed it gets.  A disadvantage is that you must record the change, and a file that is accidentally deleted, then resurrected, can get a new ID (see ClearCase "evil twins").

Git simply re-discovers the rename, every time it goes to compare one commit to another (or a commit to the index, or the index to the work-tree, etc).  This means you do not *have* to use `git mv`: you can `git rm --cached` the old path and `git add` the new one, to get the same effect.  (You can, of course, use `git mv` whenever it is more convenient, which is most of the time.  But this is a significant difference from version control systems that record, with each check-in or commit, directory modifications: with these systems you must invoke the VCS-specific `mv` command, such as `hg mv` or `cleartool mv`, to inform the VCS that the file moved, rather than letting the VCS figure it out later.)

Comment: Voted up for the **amazing stuff** i have learned from it. but i have one question: the last paragraph - `you don't have to use git mv`. If you rename a file (mv) without git mv git will track it as new file. (see this as example - http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCUeT.png) so according to your git should it see as a rename, but it doesnt. What do i miss here

Comment: If you rename a file without informing Git, (e.g., `mv foo bar`), Git won't know to `git add bar` and `git rm --cached foo` until you tell it to do so. Once you *do* tell it, Git will be caught up again. Using `git mv foo bar` will both rename the file *and* tell git to take out the old index entry and add the new one, all in one convenient pass, so it's the way to go—it's just not technically *required*, as Git will figure it out once you take care of the rest later. (In Mercurial, the `hg mv` *is* required, but you can spell it `hg mv --after` if you already `mv`ed outside `hg`. [continued]

Comment: [...continued] This is a significant difference between Git and Mercurial: Git *reconstructs* changes while Mercurial *tracks* changes.  Mercurial's commits are in fact changesets rather than snapshots.)

Comment: Ok, it was not clear to me that you mean to add//remove file by yourself. from you answer it sound like git will track it by itself which we know it will not. it will require 2 separate manual commands.