# Java project source folders are missing after Git pull but Eclipse says they exist

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I pulled a project from my Git repository but the `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources` source folders do not appear. They were empty before I pushed, and when I tried cloning the repo on a different computer I did not get these source folders.

I even tried creating them manually, but Eclipse says they already exist, so I'm stuck with the warning/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They were empty before I pushed

git does not add empty content. 
So if no file in them they will not be commited.

The convention is to put dummy file in the folder named `.gitkeep' so git will track the folders.
The reason is that git does not track file names or folders. it track content and if there is no content it does not track it.

---

Git store only content and if there is no content it does not track it.
You can read a bit about it here:
[How does git status work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922197/how-does-git-status-work-internally/36922283#36922283)

Comment: Ok can you explain why Eclipse says they exist and wouldn't let me create? I had to manually create the folders through my OS

Comment: Eclipse create them for you :-).

Comment: Ok, and why is the dummy file named '.gitkeep' and not 'gitkeep'? Why should we add a '.' before gitkeep?

Comment: Since in unix dot file are hidden files. Unix convention