# How does git know that i'm in a subdirectory

Tags: git

I noticed that when I'm inside a subdirectory of a git directory, it is still able to recognize the parent `.git` file. How does it work?

My assumption is that when I run `git status` it will search the current directory for a `.git` file and if it does not exist it will search the parent directory for it.

Is this correct?

To give an example, I have this directory lay out:

```
~/folder/
    .git
    subfolder/
        subsubfolder/
```

If I run `git status` while inside the subsubfolder, it is able to show the file changes that is registered in .git.

Comment: Try to see this complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922197/how-does-git-status-work-internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My assumption is that when I run `git status` it will search the current directory for a `.git` file and if it does not exist it will search the parent directory for it. Is this correct?

That, with some minor corrections and a *lot* of caveats, is indeed the heart of the algorithm.  Some details are Git-version-specific, some are OS-dependent, and some are compile-time options.

The minor correction that is version-dependent is that `.git` may be required to be a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term).  The ability to have a `.git` *file*, containing the path name of the actual repository directory, went in about the same time as new `git worktree` code, around Git 2.5, I think.

The biggest caveat is that if the environment variable `GIT_DIR` is set, it *must* contain the pathname under which the repository will be found.  When it is *not* set, Git implements the searching method you described: start in the current working directory (`getcwd` from C code, `os.getcwd` in Python, etc), and if no `.git` can be found, climb up one level—adding one `..`, or stripping off one path name component—and try again.  The search stops when:

- Git reaches `/` so there is no higher position, or
- Git reaches a file system *mount point*, on those systems that have it and have this compiled in, and environment variable `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM` is not set.

The front end command, `git`, actually does this, and sets `GIT_DIR` in the environment for the underlying implementation command so that the search need not be repeated.  Note that the front end command executes any `-C` (change-directory) directives first.  Hence, if `$GIT_DIR` is set and contains a *relative* path name, it is used *after* the `-C` directive is run.