# how does git log --follow <filename> work?

Tags: git

Im trying to pick an id for a file's history -- i'd like it to be or refer to the "object" whose details `git log --follow <filename>`. I'm wondering:

How does git know that one file is a variant of another across subsequent commits? The name being the same is a strong hint, of course, but it also tracks renaming on commit. Does it keep the results of its calculations somewhere for git log to refer to (where?), or does git log repeat these calculations every time? (And what calculations are these?)

Ideally I'd like to access or recreate the history (list of commits/blob shas) with nodegit.

Comment: Don't quote me on this (ask @torek) but I actually think  Git uses a sort of regex to track filenames across commits.  Note that Git has a hard time tracking across renaming; if you're very concerned about a file history then consider _not_ renaming it.

Comment: I just want to figure out how git does it so I can recreate it and/or look it up. (Quality of fit is secondary problem for the moment -- I need a general solution and think git might be a good starting point.)

Comment: Allow me to clarify: Git looks for an exact match, and if that fails then it pulls out a regex.  An exact match would only not be found either for new files or for files whose name changed.

Comment: I take it this is a regex for the filenames, to spot renaming (or moving)? It also checks file content, right? If you can put a link/explanation of the algorithm I'd be pleased to accept that as an answer... but want enough details to recreate (or at least look and decide to simplify if its too complex for me).

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938582/how-does-git-detect-similar-files-for-its-rename-detection

Comment: Git does not store in any way, shape, or form, that a rename/move has taken place. This is entirely the tooling on top of the underlying repository. In other words, if you examine the git objects that make up these commits, their trees, and the files they contain, you will not find mention of anything that was renamed or moved. Instead, when necessary, git analyzes the data (again) to (again) figure out what happened.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It doesn't apply regex matching to the file names. It *does* do exact content matching first (by hash ID), and then "similarity scoring" by an undocumented algorithm (in [diffcore-delta.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diffcore-delta.c)) that actually just hashes lines-or-line-fragments. It also checks whether the "base name" of the two files match; if so this boosts the match-chance. This same code is used to find similar blobs when building pack files.

Comment: @torek Fire an answer away if you feel like it :-)   I remembered the part about exact matching and then falling back to something else.  Maybe this is enough info for this question.

Comment: @torek, TimBiegeleisen if someone wants to pull together description and references (also see ref by j6t ) I will accept....

Comment: That's a fair bit of work, or a link-heavy answer :-) (basically we either have to describe the code, or link to the code, in the two diffcore files). Worse, though, is that these things are internal implementation details. In particular `--follow` depends on some shortcuts that only work in the "backwards" direction (I looked at this long ago for `git log --reverse --follow` if you know the *original* name of a file). Some future Git might change some of these details, and then you'd be stuck with an incompatible implementation...

Comment: @torek -- how about just links with a short summary of how it works (best would be a restatement of "the summary in git internals manual", but it doesn't exist there -- so this would be the "go to place" before wading into the code. :))

Comment: @shaunc: I couldn't resist delving deeper. :-)

Comment: @torek -- wish I could mark as twice answered!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both other people and I have described this in different (and no links) detail elsewhere, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292993/1256452) to [What's git's heuristic for assigning content modifications to file paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292562/1256452) or my answer to [Git Diff of same files in two directories always result in "renamed"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40351574/1256452).  The details are slightly different for `git log --follow` than they are for `git diff`, since `git diff` usually deals with an entire tree-full of left and right side files, but `git log --follow` only works with one particular path.<sup>1</sup>

In any case, the rename-following happens when comparing two specific commits.  For a general `git diff` they are *any* two commits *R* (right side) and *L* (left side—you choose the two),<sup>2</sup> but for `git log` they are specifically parent and child.  Let's call these *P* and *C* for convenience.  With `git log --follow`, Git runs an after-diff step (called from `diff_tree_sha1`; see footnotes) that trims everything down to one file.  The diff is done with *R=C* and *L=P*.  The general case is actually easier to describe, though, so we'll start with that.

Normally, when comparing *R* vs *L*, Git:

- matches up all the tree files that have the same full path name, then
- puts the remaining files (paths) into a pairing queue.

You can modify this a bit with the `-B` (pair-**b**reaking) flag, which actually takes two optional integers (`-Bn/m`).  Only the *`n`* integer matters for rename detection.<sup>3</sup>  You can modify it with the `-C` flag as well; this takes only an optional *`n`*, and turns on *copy detection*.  In all cases *rename detection* must be turned on.  Rename detection is enabled via `-M`, which likewise takes an optional integer *`n`*, or automatically in the case of `git log --follow` and other commands like `git status` or the post-merge `git diff --stat`.

In any case, the integer *`n`* here is a *similarity* (or dissimilarity) metric value for all of these various options.  This is where we get to the meat of the rename detection code.

Suppose that we have, to start with, a basic `git diff <commit1> <commit2>` or `git diff <tree1> <tree2>` operation.  This winds up calling [`builtin_diff_tree` in `builtin/diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/builtin/diff.c#L158), which calls `diff_tree_sha1` (which we'll see again later) and then [`log_tree_diff_flush` in `log-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/log-tree.c#L726).  This almost immediately calls [`diffcore_std` in `diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L5007), which runs the the `diffcore_break`, `diffcore_rename`, and `diffcore_merge_broken` functions if the right (`-B`, `-M` or `-C`, and `-B` again) options are selected.

These three functions operate on a *pairing queue*. How does the pairing queue get set up?  I'll leave that to another section since it's complicated.  For now, just assume that the pairing queue already has `path/to/file` matched with `path/to/file` when there's a `path/to/file` in both *L* and *R*, and otherwise has an unpaired `path/to/L-only` and `path/to/R-only` for cases where there's a file-path that occurs only in *L* or only in *R*.

The [`diffcore_break` function is in `diffcore-break.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-break.c#L117).  Its job is to find already-paired files whose *dis*similarity index (when comparing the *L* and *R* versions) is above some threshold.  If that's the case, it breaks the pairing.  The `diffcore_merge` function is just below it in the same file; it rejoins a broken-up pair if neither half has found a "better mate".  The dissimilarity index computation is similar to, but not the same as, the similarity computation.<sup>4</sup>

#### Similarity detection

The more interesting [`diffcore_rename` function is in `diffcore-rename.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L444).  It has [a special case shortcut for `--follow`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L463-L465) that we can ignore for now.  It then looks for [exact renames](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L507), i.e., files whose blob hashes match, even though their names don't.  There are some fiddly bits for using "the next file" if multiple *L* sources have the same hash as some unpaired *R* destination, too.

Next, it [checks how many unpaired entries there are](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L380), because it is going to (in effect) do num(*L*) times num(*R*) comparisons of files to compute their similarities, and this is going to take a lot of time and space.  It will even automatically downgrade a `--find-copies-harder` case that is "too hard".  Then, for each possible *L* and *R* pairing, it computes a [similarity index *and* a name score](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L560-L565).

The similarity index code is in [`estimate_similarity` in `diffcore-rename.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L130).  It relies on the function [`diffcore_count_changes` in `diffcore-delta.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L130), which says this (I'm copying it straight from the file since it's one of the core metrics):

```
 * Idea here is very simple.
 *
 * Almost all data we are interested in are text, but sometimes we have
 * to deal with binary data.  So we cut them into chunks delimited by
 * LF byte, or 64-byte sequence, whichever comes first, and hash them.
 *
 * For those chunks, if the source buffer has more instances of it
 * than the destination buffer, that means the difference are the
 * number of bytes not copied from source to destination.  If the
 * counts are the same, everything was copied from source to
 * destination.  If the destination has more, everything was copied,
 * and destination added more.
 *
 * We are doing an approximation so we do not really have to waste
 * memory by actually storing the sequence.  We just hash them into
 * somewhere around 2^16 hashbuckets and count the occurrences.
```

There's a secret bit here though: [the similarity index ignores `\r` characters if the file is considered "not binary" and the `\r` is immediately followed by `\n`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-delta.c#L147).

The [final similarity index score](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-rename.c#L204) is:

```
score = (int)(src_copied * MAX_SCORE / max_size);
```

where `src_copied` is the number of hashed chunks (of 64 bytes or up-to-newline) that occurred in the source and then occurred again in the destination, and `max_size` is the size, in bytes, of whichever blob is larger.  (This byte count does not account for stripped `'\r'` characters.  Those are merely removed from the 64-or-up-to-newline chunks being hashed.)

The "name score" is really just 1 (same base name) or 0 (different base name), i.e., 1 if the *L* file is `dir/oldbase` and the *R* file is `differentdir/oldbase`, but 0 if the *L* file is `dir/oldbase` and the *R* file is `anything/newbase`.  This is used to make Git favor `newdir/oldbase` over `anything/newbase` when those two files are equally similar.

#### Creating the pairing queue

The `diff_tree_sha1` code calls (through a series of functions) [`ll_diff_tree_paths`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/tree-diff.c#L406) (both are in in `tree-diff.c`; I linked only to the final function here).  This is a complicated and extremely optimized bit of code (Git spends a lot of time here) so we'll just do a quick overview and ignore the complications (see footnote 2).  This code looks partly at the *full path names* of each blob in each tree (these are the P1,...,Pn items in the comment at the top), and partly at the blob hashes for each of these names.  For files that have the same name *and* the same contents, it does nothing (except in `--find-copies-harder` mode in which case it queues *all* file names).  For files that have the same name and *different* contents, or no *L* or *R* name, it calls (through function pointers, stored in `opt->pathchange`, `opt->change`, and `opt->add_remove`) what eventually boil down to [`diff_change`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L5128) or [`diff_addremove`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L5082), both in `diff.c`.  These call [`diff_queue`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L4172), which put the file pair (one of which is a dummy if the file is new or removed) into the pairing queue.

Hence, the short version (if we're not using `-C` or `--find-copies-harder`), the pairing queue has *unpaired* files only when there is no original source file in *L* corresponding to a file in *R*, or no destination file in *R* corresponding to a source file in *L*.  With `-C`, it has every source file, or every modified source file, listed as well so that they can be scanned for copies (the choice here being based on whether you used `--find-copies-harder`).

#### Reducing this to one file, for `--follow`

We already noted a shortcut in the `diffcore-rename.c` code: it skips over all *R* file names that are not the one file name we care about.  There seem to be some similar hacks in `ll_diff_tree_paths`, although I am not sure whether they apply here.  The code is also driven in a different way, as noted in footnote 2.  When we diff parent *P* vs child *C*, and find a rename left in our pairing queue, we then switch out the name of the file we're using as a restriction in our `git log -- <path>`: we replace the new name in *C* with the path for the rename-source in *P*.  Then we just continue diffing as usual, so the next time we compare a *P*-and-*C* pair, we're looking for `oldpath` instead of `newpath`.  If we detect `oldpath` as being renamed from `reallyoldpath`, we switch that name into place again, as before.

Note that all the `-B`, `-C`, and `-M` machinery applies *in theory*, but the shortcuts may—it's not at all clear to me whether they do—keep some of it from working.

---

<sup>1</sup>When using `--follow`, Git uses the general diffcore code to run both pair-breaking and copy-detection.  The general code is *called from* the code that wants to do the simplification.  See the function [`try_to_follow_renames` in `tree-diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/tree-diff.c#L580), which calls [`diffcore_std` in `diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L5007).  This all eventually calls [`diff_resolve_rename_copy`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diff.c#L4385) which handles the pairing queues.  Then `try_to_follow_renames` trims the result down to the one interesting file; this is later tested via [`diff_might_be_rename`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/tree-diff.c#L574) as called from [`diff_tree_sha1`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/tree-diff.c#L697).  I think this is all driven from [`log_tree_commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/log-tree.c#L856), called from either [`cmd_log_walk`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/builtin/log.c#L343) or [`log_show_early`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/builtin/log.c#L251).  This last appears to be an undocumented hack meant for use by some GUI(s).

<sup>2</sup>The tree matching in `git diff` actually accepts a single commit on the output right-hand side, and a *list* of commits on the input left-hand side, for combined diff purposes.  This is how Git manages to show merge commits.  It's a bit unclear how `--follow` works with merge commits though.  See [`find_paths_generic` in combine-diff.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/combine-diff.c#L1314), which calls `diff_tree_sha1` as well.  Note that the `log --follow` hack happens as a result of calling `diff_tree_sha1`, and this combined-diff merge-handling code calls that function once *per parent.*  If the followed name will be changed, though, it *has been* changed by the time it goes through the second parent.  Perhaps this is a bug.  What happens if that second parent decides the new name results in another, different rename?  Logically, it should choose up to one new name per parent-fork, working in topological order, and consider resolving them again somehow if and when the forks rejoin.

<sup>3</sup>The second, *`m`*, value in `-Bn/m` tells Git when not to run a real diff, and instead just describe the change in a *non*-renamed file as "delete all the original lines, replace them with all the new lines".  That assumes that either the first `-B`value ended up *not* breaking the pairing, or the pairing was re-glued-together due to the `-M` value, or glued to a different source as a `-C` copy.

<sup>4</sup>See [`should_break`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b06d3643105c8758ed019125a4399cb7efdcce2c/diffcore-break.c#L8) for details.  This also uses the `diffcore-delta.c` code, but in a different way, using the "added" count.

Answer (score 1):

`git log` repeats the calculations every time.

The decision is based on file contents. When one file goes away, and another file appears, Git compares the contents and decides that the file was renamed if the contents are equal or very similar (by some measure).

Comment: ok ... so... is there an algorithm? I tried looking in git internals, but perhaps I didn't know where to look. A reference would be great.

Comment: Look for [diffcore-rename.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diffcore-rename.c).